# What effect will a space-elevator have on Earth's rotational speed?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, planets, estimation

If you (or e.g. a skater) spin on the spot with your arms outstretched you spin at a given speed, but when you retract your arms you spin much faster, extending your arms again will slow the spin down. Your arms are small in relation to your body but has a big effect in this case. Would a space-elevator have the same effect on earth's rotational speed, and by how much?

Comment: You should read the following information: http://users.wpi.edu/~paravind/Publications/PKASpace%20Elevators.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it will be of order $\frac {m_{elevator}}{m_{earth}}$ (quite small compared to your skater's arms example) and also depend on the latitude of where it is tethered.

Comment: if Guy's guys bring back a big asteroid & the tether is at some high latitude it would put a wobble in earth's rotation and we all get seasick :)

Answer (score 1):

Building the elevator will slow the earth by a negligible amount. Over time, launching spacecraft will slow it more but bringing back ore from the asteroid mines will speed it back up.